# retrieve data from oracle database using the select statement and load to a vector

Tags: c++, oracle11g, resultset

help!!! i am going to retrieve data from oracle database using the select statement and load to a vector.

```
SELECT *From table
```

where table contains ID,NAME and Age with over 100 elements
.... so can i have a simple technique to retrieve the values using c++(console) using the `resultset.`
.........

```
 //here my struct first.
        struct adopp
        {
        int age,
        string name;
        string id;
        };
    //the vector to load
      vector<string> load()
            {
                    oc::Environment* evt = oc::Environment::createEnvironment(oc::Environment::DEFAULT);//oracle::occi::
                    oc::Connection* con=evt->createConnection("usr","psw", "db");
                    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";
                    oc::Statement *sttmnt = con->createStatement(sqlQuery);
                    oc::ResultSet* rset = sttmnt->executeQuery();
                   vector<string>vet;
                   adopp adp;
                   while(rset->next())
                    {
                        string iddd= rset->getString(1);
                                    adp.id=iddd;
                        vet.push_back(iddd);    
                        string nameee= rset->getString(2);
                                    adp.name=nameee;                
                                    vet.push_back(nameee);
                        int age=rset->getint(3);
                                    adp.age=ageee;      
                        vet.push_back(ageee);
                    }
                    con->terminateStatement(sttmnt);
                    evt->terminateConnection(con);
                    oc::Environment::terminateEnvironment(evt);
                return vet;
            }
```

The Error/Exception popup message says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x53cbad4a (msvcp100d.dll) in Test_project_L.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccd0.
```

[image: p]

thanks for your help.

Comment: To start with, why not have a vector of structures containing the three fields instead? Secondly, you try to get the age as a string but assign it to an integer variable, and then push it into the vector as a string. That won't work very well. Other than that there's really no other way to handle this than the way you already do.

Comment: hay thanks for your time to help me.but, i have the same error still.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the error was, no?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the understanding of your question and [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241882/unhandled-exception-at-0x523d14cf-msvcr100d-dll)

Kindly change

```
while(rset->next())
```

to

```
 while(rset->next()!= NULL)
```